# Search numeric value upto 3 words before a particular word

Tags: r, regex

Is it possible to search for numeric value upto 3 words before a particular word let's say `years` via regex? In the example below I am searching for a word before `years`, it works but if you look at third element it returns `more`. Here I need `2` instead. Pattern of `XX or more years` is not fixed, hence I am trying to find numeric value upto 3 words before `years`

```
Description <- c("Candidate having bachelor degree. Minimum 5 years in R", "Excellent academic background plus 3 years of experience in Python", "Analytics Professionals having minimum of 2 or more years of experience", "Candidate possessing credit risk experience plus 2+ years in Python", "Candidate possessing credit risk experience plus two or more years in Python")

[1] "Candidate having bachelor degree. Minimum 5 years in R"                      
[2] "Excellent academic background plus 3 years of experience in Python"          
[3] "Analytics Professionals having minimum of 2 or more years of experience"     
[4] "Candidate possessing credit risk experience plus 2+ years in Python"         
[5] "Candidate possessing credit risk experience plus two or more years in Python"
```

**Code**

```
str_extract(Description, "\\w+(\\+)?(?= +years(\\s+of)?(\\s+programming|experience)?\\b)")
[1] "5"    "3"    "more" "2+"
```

Comment: If you need numeric, then `str_replace(Description, ".*\\b([0-9]+)\\b[^0-9]+\\byears.*", "\\1")
[1] "5" "3" "2" "2"`

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works like a charm. Need suggestion - Can we expand it to find words of numericals like one, two, etc? english::english(1:9) returns [1] one   two   three four  five  six   seven eight nine I mean extending solution from just numeric to english words of numeric

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari Regex that matches English numerals is very long, do you want to match up to a specific amount only? Maybe from 1 to 99 only?

Comment: Only 1 through 9. english::english(1:9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use a named vector to replace the `english` elements to numeric, and then do the extraction

```
library(stringr)
library(english)
as.numeric(str_replace(str_replace_all(Description, 
    setNames(as.character(1:9), as.character(english(1:9)))), 
    ".*\\b([0-9]+)\\b[^0-9]+\\byears.*", "\\1"))
```

-output

```
[1] 5 3 2 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not being so clear. I meant if I have English numeric words in the text. Refer fifth element I added in the post. I need 2 for this case.

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari you can check the update